# PDF Section 508 - block of text couldn't be tagged

Tags: pdf, tags, section508

I had a paragraph of text (in the containers as well) that TURO would not pick up as a tagged text/paragraph.  When I went into containers and manually dragged the actual text out of the container wrap so that it was a stand along text tag in container view, it magically reappared in the tag tree and I could finish the 508 work.  JAWS finally read the paragraph as well.

What caused this issue in the first place?  Would it be something in the security preferences or something, because the source was just a plain old MS Word document.

I manually dragged the text out of the container wrap it was in